# Why are traces an analogue to integrals?

Tags: etale-cohomology, traces

In Poincare duality for singular cohomology, one integrates cohomology classes against a fundamental class to get a number $\int_{[M]} \omega$.

In the formulation of Poincare duality in etale cohomology, this integration is replaced with the construction of a trace map $\text{tr}_{X/S}(\mathscr{F}): R^{2d} f_! (f^* \mathscr{F}(d)) \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}$.

(I don't actually see why this should be called a "trace" in the sense of linear algebra, but never mind that.)

I've also seen traces of Frobenius on stalks regarded as the analogue of a local residue.

What is the motivation behind this analogy? Why are traces the right notion to replace integrals in etale cohomology?

Comment: If $V$ is a vector space over a field $k$, then the canonical pairing $\mathrm{End}(V) = V\otimes V^\ast \to k$ is the trace function. In Serre duality for a smooth proper curve $C$ over $k$, for instance, you can consider $V = \mathrm{H}^0(C, \Omega^1_C)$, and then the dual space $V^\ast$ admits a canonical description as $\mathrm{H}^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C)$. Integration defines a map $V\otimes V^\ast \to k$, and this is the canonical pairing, and therefore may also be called the "trace".

Comment: Does this explain why $\text{tr}_{X/S}(\mathscr{F}): R^{2d} f_! (f^* \mathscr{F}(d)) \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}$ should be seen as a trace?

Comment: Yes. If $\mathcal{F}$ is an 'etale sheaf on a $d$-dimensional smooth projective scheme over $k$ (can also do over any base), then the cup product defines a pairing $\mathrm{H}^{2d-p}(X; \mathcal{F})\otimes \mathrm{Ext}^q(\mathcal{F}, \mu_n^d) \to \mathrm{H}^{2d}(X, \mu_n^d)$. This is a perfect pairing, and the trace map identifies $\mathrm{H}^{2d}(X, \mu_n^d)$ with $\mathbf{Z}/n$. The analogue in topology is the identification of the top de Rham cohomology group of a smooth closed manifold with $\mathbf{R}$ by integration of differential forms.

Comment: It's best to think about this explicitly in the case when $X$ is a smooth projective curve over $\mathbf{C}$. You can then rely on GAGA to compare with your intuition from classical topology.

Comment: Why should the identification $\text{H}^{2d}(X,\mu_n^d) \longrightarrow \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ be called a trace? It does not have the form of the trace (i.e. $V \otimes V^*$) you described.

Comment: The composite $\mathrm{H}^{2d-p}(X; \mathcal{F})\otimes \mathrm{Ext}^q(\mathcal{F}, \mu_n^d) \to \mathrm{H}^{2d}(X, \mu_n^d) \cong \mathbf{Z}/n$ implements the canonical identification of $\mathrm{Ext}^q(\mathcal{F}, \mu_n^d)$ with the $\mathbf{Z}/n$-linear dual of $\mathrm{H}^{2d-p}(X; \mathcal{F})$. Under that identification, the composite $\mathrm{H}^{2d-p}(X; \mathcal{F}) \otimes \mathrm{H}^{2d-p}(X; \mathcal{F})^\ast \to \mathbf{Z}/n$ is literally the trace pairing.

Comment: But here you are referring to the composition, not the identification, which is what is typically called the trace map.